# Find out reason for form instancing

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2017

In my application, a certain form is instanciated, and I have no idea why this happens.

I would therefore like to ask if it's possible to detect the "caller" that loads / instanciates the form.

Is it possible to get it from here?

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
```

Or is there any other way how I could do this?

Edit:
This is the callstack:
[image]

Comment: You could set a breakpoint and look at the call stack

Comment: If you don't want to stop execution you can also access the current call stack _without_ breakpoints using [**`Environment.StackTrace`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Plutonix I've edited my question and added a screenshot of the call stack. However, I don't really see where the form instancing arises from. Do you?

Comment: Isn't `frmMain` your main form and supposed to be opened by your application? Otherwise I'd check inside the `clsButtonList.Render()` method. Also check any timers that you might have.

Comment: By the way, are you by any chance trying to access `frmMain` from a background thread?

Comment: Right mouse click `Public Class frmMain` and click "Find All References"

Comment: You should be able to single-step out of the ctor right back to the origin

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, I do, isn't that allowed?

Comment: No, all gui work has to be on the main thread.

Comment: I don't access frmMain from within the background worker anymore, and my problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was due to that you were accessing `frmMain`'s [**default instance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/default-object-instances-provided-by-my-forms-and-my-webservices) from a background thread.

VB.NET includes default instances of every form so that you don't have to do a `Dim ... As New myForm` every time you want to open a new form. This behaviour will let you shorten:

```
Dim mainForm As New frmMain
mainForm.Show()
```

to:

```
frmMain.Show()
```

And although not specifically documented, from previously conducting my own test it appears that the default instance is specific to the current thread **only**. Thus if you try to access the default form instance **in any way** from a background thread it will create a new instance for *that specific thread*, and therefore not be the same as the one you're using on the UI thread.

In the end this brings us to one of the golden rules of WinForms, which LarsTech mentioned: *Leave all (G)UI related work **on the (G)UI thread!***

---

If you really need to access your first instance of `frmMain` from a background thread you should make a `Shared` property that returns that specific instance:

```
Private Shared _instance As frmMain = Nothing

Public Shared ReadOnly Property MainInstance As frmMain
    Get
        Return _instance
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If frmMain._instance Is Nothing Then frmMain._instance = Me 'Setting the main instance if none exists.
End Sub
```

Then from a background thread you'll be able to do:

```
frmMain.MainInstance.DoSomething
```

Comment: And the Silver Rule: Never use VB's default instances.  They were a mistake to add, and they will turn around a bite you the first chance they get.

Comment: @BradleyUffner What exactely do you mean by default instance? frmMain is my start form. I see no other way to access it than by using frmMain.DoSomething.

Comment: @tmighty Forms are classes, just like any other class in .NET, they just have a special designer.  As such, you can do `Dim frm as New frmMain()` to create a new instance, and `frm.DoSomething` to call a method on the instance.  You can pass the `frm` variable around to other things, or even create multiple copies of `frmMain` with different calls to `New`.

Comment: Yes, I only did it this way because VS urges me to use a Start Form to have visual styles, single instance application and Shutdown mode. I did try to avoid it, but at some point I simply gave in.

Comment: @tmighty : And here I thought you understood what default instances are from my answer ;). Putting it simply the default instance is created automatically (unless it already exists) when you call `frmMain.DoSomething`. It lets you access `frmMain` directly without having to `Dim frm As New frmMain`. C# for example doesn't have this behaviour, so if you'd call `frmMain.DoSomething;` it would give you an error because you have to initialize the form first: `frmMain frm = new frmMain();  frm.DoSomething;`. The default instances remove the need of you creating a new form instance before using it.

Comment: That's not just a golden rule of WinForms, it's a golden rule of all .NET UI.

Comment: @VisualVincent Let's assume, my main application window is "frmMain". In the VS project properties, VS asks me which one my "Startup Form" is. I select "frmMain". Now when I want to access frmMain from modules, I need to say frmMain.DoSomething. If I instanciate it again, I would have 2 frmMain appearing, that's not what I want. Is there something I don't understand from your answer?

Comment: @tmighty : Nono, you can still access the default instance _from the UI thread_. But you should avoid trying to access it from a _background thread_. What I said about instantiation was merely to give you a hint of the difference.

Comment: @tmighty : If you really need to access that specific form from a background thread you should make a shared property that holds the instance of the very first `frmMain`. I have added an example of this to my answer.