# VB.net trying to access a UI element from seperate thread is not working

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a rich text box in my main for that I want to write stuff to from different threads. I have tried to do this using invoking, but I can't seem to get it to work. If I try it with:

```
If InvokeRequired Then
    Dim Dgate As writeLogDelegate = New writeLogDelegate(AddressOf writeLog)
    BeginInvoke(Dgate, New Object() {Message})
Else
    RTB_Log.AppendText(Message)
End If
```

then InvokeRequired does not return `true` like it should and checking if the handle is created returns `false`, but on form load, if I get the value of **IsHandleCreated**, it returns `true`. My method for trying to invoke writing is like so:

Thread Class snippet:

```
Public Sub startClientPoll(ByRef Sender As TcpListener)
    Dim TThread As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf pollClientConnect))
    TThread.Start(Sender)
End Sub
Private Sub pollClientConnect(tcplistener As TcpListener)
    Do
        If tcplistener.Pending() Then
            'MessageBox.Show("")
            RaiseEvent clientConnecting()
        End If
    Loop Until Ended = True
End Sub
```

Event handler class snippet:

```
Private Sub client_Connect() Handles listenerSocket.clientConnecting
    Form1.writeLog("New client awaiting accept" & vbNewLine)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient = listenerSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
    Dim clientHandler As New MPClientReciever(clientSocket)
End Sub
```

Main form snippet:

```
Public Sub writeLog(ByVal Message As String)
    If Not IsHandleCreated Then
        CreateControl()
    End If
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Dim Dgate As writeLogDelegate = New writeLogDelegate(AddressOf writeLog)
        BeginInvoke(Dgate, New Object() {Message})
    Else
        RTB_Log.AppendText(Message)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Form1.writeLog...` that looks like a default form instance which dont do well with threads

Comment: If thats so is there a better method of doing it?

Comment: Are you creating a control `CreateConrol()` in a background thread?

Comment: Yes I am but thats because the form doesnt seem to have a handle even though it does when its in `Form1_Load`.

Comment: Default instances are thread-specific. That means that if you display a default instance on the UI thread and then refer to a default instance on a secondary thread then you're actually referring to a different form. You need a reference to the actual `Form1` object that you displayed in the first place rather than using the default instance in that case.

Comment: In addition to jmcilhinney's comment you must pass the current `Form1` instance to your thread class. If you only have one `Form1` open at a time you can see this answer for a workaround (in the bottom): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948766

Comment: @VisualVincent in that link you posted why is it `If frmMain._instance IsNot Nothing Then` instead of `If frmMain._instance Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: Whoops, typo. Thanks for pointing it out! It should be `Is Nothing` like you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a Sub globally on your class as the following:

```
Private Delegate Sub AddText_DL(ByVal txtControl As Control, ByVal txtVAL As String, ByVal append As Boolean)
Private Sub AddText(ByVal txtControl As Control, ByVal txtVAL As String, ByVal append As Boolean)
    If txtControl.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Dim progDel As New AddText_DL(AddressOf AddText)
        Dim parameters(2) As Object
        parameters(0) = txtControl
        parameters(1) = txtVAL
        parameters(2) = append
        txtControl.Invoke(progDel, parameters)
    Else
        If append = True Then
            txtControl.text &= txtVAL
        Else
            txtControl.text = txtVAL
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To use it in different threads, call

```
AddText(MyTextBoxObject, "add this text please, don't append", False)
```

And for your reference, if you want to access a UI control's property and get its set value, you can instead use:

```
Private Delegate Function CheckedStatus_DL(ByVal checkable As Control) As Boolean
Function CheckedStatus(ByVal checkable As Control) As Boolean
    If checkable.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Dim gridDel As New CheckedStatus_DL(AddressOf CheckedStatus)
        Dim parameters(0) As Object
        parameters(0) = checkable
        Return checkable.Invoke(gridDel, parameters)
    Else
        Return checkable.checked
    End If
End Function
```

Also you can use this `Function` with any control that has `.Checked` property

Comment: Don't encourage late binding. Declare the control prameter as `ByVal txtControl As Control` instead. That way you also impose a restriction on what you can pass to the method.

Comment: I had to set a reference to the form that was available to the thread so you could call `instance.DoSomething`, thanks for everyone's help

Comment: @VisualVincent true I agree about late binding, I edited it. Thanks for pointing it out