# Start a thread for a sub inside a class

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety

What im trying to do is start a thread of a Sub which is inside a class , that will change form1's label1.text . Apparently this code doesnt work .

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Class test
        Public Sub doit()
            Form1.chan("hello")
        End Sub
    End Class
    Delegate Sub changeit(ByVal test As String)

    Public Sub chan(ByVal test As String)
        If Me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New changeit(AddressOf chan)
            Me.Invoke(d, {test})
        Else
            Me.Label1.Text = test
            Label1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim a As New test
        Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf a.doit)
        thread.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does that even compile? Since `chan` is not `Shared` I would expect `Form.chan("hello")` to give a compile error. But, I'm not so experience with VB.

Comment: @Crowcoder : In VB.NET there's this thing called _Default Instances_ for forms. The way they work is that once you access `Form1` (or any other form for that matter) by its name a new instance of it is created unless one already exists in the current thread. That instance you can then show, modify and interact with via the form's name until it is disposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out reason for form instancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947911/find-out-reason-for-form-instancing)