# Update TextBox in Runtime. Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: vb.net, tcp, delegates, thread-safety

I am doing a TCP connection client/server and I really want to update a label or textbox in runtime, for that I am  using a delegate that it's working fine but when I am trying update Form1 is not working at all like I'd like.

In the code below I explain what I am doing.

I have a class called Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
Public server As tcp_server
Private Shared _instance As Form1 = Nothing

Public Shared ReadOnly Property MainInstance As Form1
    Get
        Return _instance
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Form1._instance Is Nothing Then
        Form1._instance = Me 'Setting the main instance if none exists.
    End If

    server = New tcp_server("192.168.30.31", "5000")
    server.connect()

End Sub

Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal text As String)

Public Sub SetText(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal text As String)

    Try
        If textBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As SetTextCallback = New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {textBox, text})
        Else
            textBox.AppendText(text)


            'Me.ShowDialog()

            Form1.MainInstance.Visible = False
            Form1.MainInstance.ShowDialog()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

The error happen here `Form1.MainInstance.ShowDialog()`

`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

And other class called `tcp_server` with a method:

```
 Public Sub connect()
    Try
        Dim server_ipendpoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(m_ip_host), m_port_host)
        tcpLsn = New TcpListener(server_ipendpoint)
        tcpLsn.Start()

        tcpThd = New Thread(AddressOf waiting_client)
        tcpThd.Start()
        'Form1.Label2.Text = "Listening"
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = "Listening" & vbCrLf

    Catch ex As Exception
        is_exception = True
    End Try

End Sub
```

In this method as you can see I start to listening incoming connections.

The new thread is called `waiting_client`

```
Private Sub waiting_client()
    Try
        Dim change_name_label As New Form1.SetTextCallback(AddressOf Form1.SetText)
        change_name_label.Invoke(Form1.TextBox1, "helllllooooooooo")

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I can't update `TextBox1` in runtime. The app doesn't not refresh the windows form.

The only thing that I've got is this and it's doing:

```
Public Sub SetText(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal text As String)

    Try
        If textBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As SetTextCallback = New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {textBox, text})
        Else
            textBox.AppendText(text)
            Me.ShowDialog()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image]

But It's not the result that really want.

I want to update TextBox1, I mean change `Listening --> helllloooooo`

I've read a lot of post and I can't find a solution.

All comments or ideas It will be appreciate.

Thank's.

Comment: You can't access a form from a background thread through its default instance. Possible duplicate of [Find out reason for form instancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947911/find-out-reason-for-form-instancing)

Comment: I've already read the post but it's not helping me at all and I tried to do the same but is not working. Thank's for your commnet.

Comment: It most definitely should help you. In my answer I describe the exact phenomena that is causing your code to behave the way it currently does, namely that you cannot access `Form1` (or any other form for that matter) via its default instance in a background thread. There isn't really any other answer to your problem. -- Also please define "not working". Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: "Default Instance" refers to accessing a form directly via its name rather than having to create an instance of it such as `Dim newForm As New Form1`. VB.NET is the only language that allows you to access it directly via `Form1` (i.e. you can call `Form1.Show()` instead of `myForm.Show()`), which is actually a rather big problem if you don't know exactly how these behave. There is a plethora of questions here on SO where the underlying cause is simply lack of knowledge about how default instances work (because it is hard to know, especially since it isn't very well documented).

Comment: Sorry I was on holidays. I've already tried all that you said in that post but It's sitll the same error  **Cross-thread operation not valid...**. I can't update TextBox in runtime, the only way that I found is that I've really mentioned in my post. I am beginner in this kind of problem and I didn't find another solution. I´ll really appreciate any help or way to solve this problem. Thanks Visual Vincent.

Comment: No worries. Please update your question with the attempts you've made based on the answer I linked you to, so that I can see if you're missing anything.

Comment: I've already updated my post, but I don't know what title I should write. Thanks Visual Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are calling `ShowDialog()` everywhere, but the purpose of the `MainInstance` property was to replace *every* `Form1` call with `Form1.MainInstance`.

Specifically it's this line that causes the error:

```
change_name_label.Invoke(Form1.TextBox1, "helllllooooooooo")
```

Because it too needs to be changed to:

```
change_name_label.Invoke(Form1.MainInstance.TextBox1, "helllllooooooooo")
```

Also, you don't really have to create the `change_name_label` delegate instance used above, you can simply call:

```
Form1.MainInstance.SetText(Form1.MainInstance.TextBox1, "helllllooooooooo")
```

...and that will be enough. The `SetText()` method already takes care of the rest for you.

Now, to make your code work properly that last thing you need to do is to get rid of the `ShowDialog()` calls. You should also remove the `Try/Catch` in the `SetText()` and `waiting_client()` methods as it is bad practice to add empty ones everywhere. If you are going to put a `Try/Catch` where an error might occur you should handle it properly by either logging it or displaying it to the user (or both).

**Form1:**

```
Private Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal text As String)

Public Sub SetText(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal text As String)
    If textBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        textBox.Invoke(d, New Object() {textBox, text})
    Else
        textBox.AppendText(text)
    End If
End Sub
```

(Note that `Dim d As SetTextCallback = New SetTextCallback` can be shortened to `Dim d As New SetTextCallback`)

**tcp_server:**

```
Public Sub connect()
    Try
        Dim server_ipendpoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(m_ip_host), m_port_host)
        tcpLsn = New TcpListener(server_ipendpoint)
        tcpLsn.Start()

        tcpThd = New Thread(AddressOf waiting_client)
        tcpThd.Start()

        Form1.MainInstance.TextBox1.Text = "Listening" & vbCrLf
    Catch ex As Exception
        is_exception = True
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub waiting_client()
    Form1.MainInstance.SetText(Form1.MainInstance.TextBox1, "helllllooooooooo")
End Sub
```

Now your code should be working!

Comment: I did this change but I forgot `Dim change_name_label As New Form1.SetTextCallback(AddressOf Form1.MainInstance.SetText)`. Anyway you are right it is much easier to handle a simple call. Just the last thing, When I Should use a delegate because I understand how to use it but not when is the best momment to use it?  Thank's I really appreciate your help Visual Vincent

Comment: @CarlosZuazu : In this case you only need to use the delegate when calling [**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx). Delegates are used to be able to treat methods as if they were regular objects (you can call stuff in them, put them in variables, pass them as arguments to other methods, etc.). Right now you're passing the method that you want to run on the UI thread as an argument to `Control.Invoke()`.