# how i can run only one instance of Selenium?

Tags: .net, vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i want to access Form1 class Selenium from another class but 
problem here is whenever access to Form1 selenium another instance execute.
i only want to use only one instance .
anyone enlighten me much appreciate

```
Public Class Form1
    Public service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
    Public chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()
    Public  driver As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCollect.Click
        ' i only want to run one webdriver session not multiple session.
        Monitoring.test()
        Monitoring2.test2()

    End Sub
end class

Public Class Monitoring
    public sub test()
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com")
    end sub

end class

Public Class Monitoring2
    public sub test2()
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.yahoo.com")
    end sub

end class
```

Comment: Are the methods in those classes called from background threads? If so, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948766/3740093

Comment: it no relation with background thread. thanks

Comment: am not a VB guy, but can you tell me how are you accessing `driver` in `Monitoring` and `Monitoring1` class defined in `Form1` class?

Comment: I doubt, you are perhaps creating tow different object to access `driver` and that may be the reason you have two instances.

Comment: that right! how i can resolve this problem? if you help me much appreciate!